# Access data from another model without direct association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 models set up like this:

```
Trip
  has_many :workgroups, through: :invitations

Workgroup
  has_many :trips, through: :invitations
  has_many :employees

Employee
  belongs_to :workgroup
```

Employees are nested in workgroups.

I am trying to access employee data in the trip views. Currently, I get the following error: `undefined method 'employees'`

Can I access the **employee** data from the **trip** model without creating a direct association between the two models?

Comment: Where is the `students` method defined? How are you trying to do it now?

Comment: It's actually employees...I corrected the original post.

Comment: Do you want to get all the employees of that trip? I mean all the employees in all workgroups?

Comment: I want to display all of the employees going on a trip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to directly reference the employee data from the trip model without creating an association.

You can either add a has_many through relationship, or reference it something like this (I'm just making a guess based on your code above.)

`trip.workgroups.first.employees`

If you want to be able to view all 'students' associated in a workgroup that is associated to a trip, you'll have to add the association.

I think that you should be able to do this:

```
Employee
  has_many :trips, through: workgroup
```